# Copy multiple directories and files to a different set of specifed directories

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a batch file that can copy files from one folder structure to a different named folder structure.  The reason is these files are delivered to another party whose system/structure is setup different then mines.

Source example:

```
001\development\media\audio\final\file-abc.mp3
002\development\media\audio\final\file-xyz.mp3
```

also in the same source is:

```
001\development\media\graphics\final\file-abc.jpg
002\development\media\graphics\final\file-xyz.jpg
```

Destination example:

```
001\audio-final\file-abc.mp3
002\audio-final\file-xyz.mp3

001\graphics\_final\file-abc.jpg
002\graphics\_final\file-xyz.jpg
```

My issue is I'm only able to copy the directory structure but I'm not skilled enough to figure out how to copy the "respective" files to each 001\ 002\ folders to which each *.mp3 and *.jpg should be copied over too.  Any help would be appreciated. This will make a 3 day process faster for me. I currently have 30 folders to do this to.

Comment: why do you need a batch for this? Just take a file manager GUI program. This is faster.

Comment: I need to be able use a batch file to copy specific files within multiple directories to a new directory named structure. I tried a file manager GUI but I don't see how its easier as I still need to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Launch this in the folder that `001` and `002` folders etc are in.

```
@echo off
set "target=e:\mybackup folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do (
xcopy "%%a\development\media\audio\final\*.mp3" "%target%\%%a\audio-final\"
xcopy "%%a\development\media\graphics\final\*.jpg" "%target%\%%a\graphics\_final\"
)
```

Comment: Is `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad')` any different from `for /d %%a in (*)`?

Comment: In this case it would be equivalent I think - but the latter will not show/process hidden subdirectories.  Thanks for correcting my typo.

Comment: Odds are the OP doesn't want to process hidden directories anyway.

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, this works exactly as I needed it to. You have saved me tons of hours of manual work.